# Unable to get Azure webapp using flask_socketio to communicate with client

Tags: python, azure, websocket, flask-socketio, azure-webapps

I've deployed an Azure python webapp that uses a gunicorn WSGI server on a Linux app service following this tutorial: [Deploy Python apps to Azure App Service on Linux from Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-01). I've enabled web sockets on configuration > general settings for this webapp. I've edited application.py 1) to render an HTML template that uses socket.io.js to send a socket message to the server, and 2) uses flask_socketio to read/write message from/to the client. I run flask locally and it works fine (send ping, get pong). Unfortunately, I'm getting 400 errors when running from the webapp like:

GET https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NITy10U&sid=0b83271d69324401be8ce43057a6cc5f 400
POST https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NITy10e&sid=0b83271d69324401be8ce43057a6cc5f 400

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Some additional stuff:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PingPong</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            namespace = ''
            var socket = io(namespace)
            socket.on("server_to_client", function (msg) {
                alert("message from server to client: " + msg.msg)
            })
            $("#run_button_id").click(function () {
                message = "ping"
                alert("mesage from client to server: " + message)
                socket.emit("client_to_server", { msg: message })
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="run_button_id">Ping</button>
</body>
</html>
```

application.py

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'notverysecret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
app.logger.debug("start app server")
app.logger.debug(app.config)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on("client_to_server")
def client_to_server(msg):
    message = "pong"
    app.logger.debug("message from server to client: " + message)
    socketio.emit("server_to_client", {"msg": message})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.1.1
flask_socketio==4.3.1
```

Comment: Did you enable Socket.IO logs? The logs show information for 400 errors,. Quite possibly you have a cross-origin issue, that is the most common source of 400s.

Comment: I enabled socket.io logging via executing this on the console: localStorage.debug = '*'; The output gives some more detail, but doesn't nail down the issue. In case it is a CORS issue, I set "allowed origins" to "*" for my webapp. Not out of the woods yet.

Comment: index.js:83 GET https://<MYSITE>.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NIrwLaH&sid=8b74fd5147244cef9a6e41fb6686db65 400
index.js:83 POST https://<MYSITE>.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NIrwNKy&sid=8b74fd5147244cef9a6e41fb6686db65 400
index.js:83 engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":400} +36s
index.js:83 socket.io-client:manager error +54s Error: xhr poll error
    at o.r.onError (index.js:83)
    at i.<anonymous> (index.js:83)
    at i.r.emit (index.js:83)
    at i.onError (index.js:83)
    at index.js:83

Comment: I meant server logs, not client logs.

Comment: I added server-side logging via: socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, cors_allowed_origins='*'). Not too much to add, but I did see some failures that looks "heartbeat" related: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '7f98e7eff7dc43428c8e6c47dd37efb8', 'upgrades': [], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NIx9jp9 HTTP/1.1" 200 107 "https://MYAPP.azurewebsites.net/"

wait...

Client is gone, closing socket
Invalid session 6c7c7c47174e49c1b55693d37980ed66

Comment: Can you edit your question with the logs? It's hard to read them in a comment. Also, in your question you said there were some 400 errors. Make sure you capture enough of the log stream to have those 400s.